# how to write isset() function?

Tags: php, html

it is only displaying not set everytime I click on the submit button. I am unable to submit the form this is a sample code my actual code is also not working nor this. if there is something wrong with my system please help me with is too.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "Button clicked";
} else{
    echo "not set";
}
?>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Sample page</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form name="form1" action="<?php echo    $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You didn't set a method on your form. The default method is `GET`, so the `POST` variable will be empty.

Comment: Your next issue will be that you are echoing a string Outside the Html Document, so likely as not you will not see anything even it it is all working correctly

Comment: @RiggsFolly — Browser error recovery will sort that. Might through the whole document into quirks mode and make CSS behave strangely though.

Comment: @Quentin And thats always fun :)

Answer (score 0):

The default value of a form's `method` attribute is `GET`. The data is being submitted in the query string where it will be available through the `$_GET` superglobal.

To move the data to the request body, where it will be available through the `$_POST` superglobal, you need to specify `method="POST"` as an attribute on the `<form>`.

Comment: thanks i got that